# regex editing tool

Tags: script, jquery

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[image: Screen shot]

### About

This is a javascript replace tool that makes editing posts easier and faster. [View readme for more info](https://github.com/user689/Scripts/blob/master/find_and_replace)

#### Download

[from github](https://github.com/user689/Scripts/blob/master/find_and_replace/main.js)

### Contact

for any issues regarding this script please post an answer here or add an issue on github.

### [Code](https://github.com/user689/Scripts/blob/master/find_and_replace)

Comment: Eeeeeek Comic Sans! Is it possible you could use a less... painful font in that screenshot? -_-

Comment: @doorknob I like that font the most.

Comment: Can there be support for other regex flavours as well?

Comment: @Unihedron AFAIK this is not possible as I'm only using `new RegExp("")`